# Nginx hangs using "service nginx start"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, docker, service, systemctl

I've compiled nginx with custom paths for my production server and when I try to start/restart the service using:

```
service nginx start
```

or

```
service nginx restart
```

It enters a new line without returning the shell:
[image: Picture of terminal when running the command]

So the problem is that I can't control nginx using `service` command. The service actually runs but it won't return a shell to me so I always have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to get it back.

I also have to mention that nginx runs just fine when calling it by its own `nginx` command and stops or reloads easily using `nginx -s stop/reload`.

This problem persists using `systemctl start nginx` as well, but `systemctl stop nginx` works just fine.

Info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
    Release:    15.10
    Codename:   wily

$ uname -r
    4.2.0-27-generic

$ nginx -V
    nginx version: nginx/1.9.11
    built by gcc 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 
    built with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
    TLS SNI support enabled
    configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-debug --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module

$ cat /etc/default/nginx
    NGINX_CONF_FILE=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    DAEMON=/usr/bin/nginx

$ cat /etc/init.d/nginx
    NGINX_BIN=/usr/bin/nginx
    test -x $NGINX_BIN || { echo "$NGINX_BIN not installed"; 
        if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
        else exit 5; fi; }
    NGINX_PID=/var/run/nginx.pid

    # Check for existence of needed config file and read it
    #NGINX_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/nginx
    #test -r $NGINX_CONFIG || { echo "$NGINX_CONFIG not existing";
    #   if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    #   else exit 6; fi; }
    #
    # Read config   
    #. $NGINX_CONFIG

    # Source LSB init functions
    # providing start_daemon, killproc, pidofproc, 
    # log_success_msg, log_failure_msg and log_warning_msg.
    # This is currently not used by UnitedLinux based distributions and
    # not needed for init scripts for UnitedLinux only. If it is used,
    # the functions from rc.status should not be sourced or used.
    #. /lib/lsb/init-functions

    # Shell functions sourced from /etc/rc.status:
    #      rc_check         check and set local and overall rc status
    #      rc_status        check and set local and overall rc status
    #      rc_status -v     be verbose in local rc status and clear it afterwards
    #      rc_status -v -r  ditto and clear both the local and overall rc status
    #      rc_status -s     display "skipped" and exit with status 3
    #      rc_status -u     display "unused" and exit with status 3
    #      rc_failed        set local and overall rc status to failed
    #      rc_failed <num>  set local and overall rc status to <num>
    #      rc_reset         clear both the local and overall rc status
    #      rc_exit          exit appropriate to overall rc status
    #      rc_active        checks whether a service is activated by symlinks
    . /etc/rc.status

    # Reset status of this service
    rc_reset

    # Return values acc. to LSB for all commands but status:
    # 0   - success
    # 1       - generic or unspecified error
    # 2       - invalid or excess argument(s)
    # 3       - unimplemented feature (e.g. "reload")
    # 4       - user had insufficient privileges
    # 5       - program is not installed
    # 6       - program is not configured
    # 7       - program is not running
    # 8--199  - reserved (8--99 LSB, 100--149 distrib, 150--199 appl)
    # 
    # Note that starting an already running service, stopping
    # or restarting a not-running service as well as the restart
    # with force-reload (in case signaling is not supported) are
    # considered a success.

    case "$1" in
        start)
        echo -n "Starting nginx "
        ## Start daemon with startproc(8). If this fails
        ## the return value is set appropriately by startproc.
        /sbin/startproc -p $NGINX_PID $NGINX_BIN

        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
        stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down nginx "
        ## Stop daemon with killproc(8) and if this fails
        ## killproc sets the return value according to LSB.

        /sbin/killproc -p $NGINX_PID -TERM $NGINX_BIN

        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
        try-restart|condrestart)
        ## Do a restart only if the service was active before.
        ## Note: try-restart is now part of LSB (as of 1.9).
        ## RH has a similar command named condrestart.
        if test "$1" = "condrestart"; then
            echo "${attn} Use try-restart ${done}(LSB)${attn} rather than condrestart ${warn}(RH)${norm}"
        fi
        $0 status
        if test $? = 0; then
            $0 restart
        else
            rc_reset    # Not running is not a failure.
        fi
        # Remember status and be quiet
        rc_status
        ;;
        restart)
        ## Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
        ## running or not, start it again.
        $0 stop
        $0 start

        # Remember status and be quiet
        rc_status
        ;;
        force-reload)
        ## Signal the daemon to reload its config. Most daemons
        ## do this on signal 1 (SIGHUP).
        ## If it does not support it, restart the service if it
        ## is running.

        echo -n "Reload service nginx "
        ## if it supports it:
        /sbin/killproc -p $NGINX_PID -HUP $NGINX_BIN
        #touch /run/nginx.pid
        rc_status -v

        ## Otherwise:
        #$0 try-restart
        #rc_status
        ;;
        reload)
        ## Like force-reload, but if daemon does not support
        ## signaling, do nothing (!)

        # If it supports signaling:
        echo -n "Reload service nginx "
        /sbin/killproc -p $NGINX_PID -HUP $NGINX_BIN
        #touch /run/nginx.pid
        rc_status -v

        ## Otherwise if it does not support reload:
        #rc_failed 3
        #rc_status -v
        ;;
        reopen)
            echo -n "Reopen the logfiles "
            /sbin/killproc -p $NGINX_PID -USR1 $NGINX_BIN
            rc_status -v
            ;;

        status)
        echo -n "Checking for service nginx "
        ## Check status with checkproc(8), if process is running
        ## checkproc will return with exit status 0.

        # Return value is slightly different for the status command:
        # 0 - service up and running
        # 1 - service dead, but /run/  pid  file exists
        # 2 - service dead, but /var/lock/ lock file exists
        # 3 - service not running (unused)
        # 4 - service status unknown :-(
        # 5--199 reserved (5--99 LSB, 100--149 distro, 150--199 appl.)

        # NOTE: checkproc returns LSB compliant status values.
        /sbin/checkproc -p $NGINX_PID $NGINX_BIN
        # NOTE: rc_status knows that we called this init script with
        # "status" option and adapts its messages accordingly.
        rc_status -v
        ;;
        probe)
        ## Optional: Probe for the necessity of a reload, print out the
        ## argument to this init script which is required for a reload.
        ## Note: probe is not (yet) part of LSB (as of 1.9)

        test /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -nt /run/nginx.pid && echo reload
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|try-restart|restart|force-reload|reload|probe}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    rc_exit
```

**UPDATE**: The problem also persists while using Docker container on CoreOS alpha.

**UPDATE 2**: Here are the outputs for `strace -o log -f service nginx start` and `journalctl -xe`:

`strace -o log -f service nginx start`
[Log output [too long to post here]](http://pastebin.com/sXzvYiH4)

---

```
    journalctl -xe
    Feb 26 07:25:38 lucifer polkitd(authority=local)[870]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8181:8813595 (system bus name :1.77 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], o
Feb 26 07:25:38 lucifer systemd[1]: Starting The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server...
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Feb 26 07:25:38 lucifer nginx[8211]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Feb 26 07:25:38 lucifer nginx[8211]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Feb 26 07:25:38 lucifer systemd[1]: nginx.service: PID file /var/run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 26 07:25:43 lucifer polkitd(authority=local)[870]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8181:8813595 (system bus name :1.77, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authen
```

Comment: Since `nginx` is working fine when starting from a cli on his own, you need to debug it's *service* script.

Comment: Try to strace the problem. It will show you what system call it can't finish. Just install strace, then strace -ff service nginx start.

Comment: @drookie @anx I have posted the results of `journalctl` and `strace` here but honestly i have no clue how to understand the problem from strace's output. i would appreciate a little bit of help, if possible.

Comment: @T0M XeOn LuCiFeR have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: Maybe related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864

Answer (score 10):

I'm having the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04, systemd and NginX 1.10.1 from source.

I was using the default `nginx.service` file:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/

The issue was the `nginx.pid` location. To fix it, I:

1. Fired up Nginx without the service

   ```
   sudo nginx start
   ```
2. Updated the locate db

   ```
   sudo updatedb
   ```
3. Found the location of the pid file

   ```
   locate "nginx.pid"
   ```
4. Updated the nginx.service file to the location where I found it

   ```
   PIDFile=/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
   ```

   (No idea why it was stored in my logs dir...)
5. Then run daemon-reload to reload the `nginx.service` file

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   ```

Afterwards, `systemctl start nginx` works like a charm. Hope this helps.

Comment: Given `/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid`as path for `PIDFile` worked for me (using ubuntu server 16.04.2 and nginx 1.12.1). Thx

Comment: It worked for me. When building nginx from source I had configured it with " --pid-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid". When I set up nginx.service, I had used wrong path and cause the same problem. When corrected, it did not caused hanging and subsequent termination. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It hangs because of this error:

```
PID file /var/run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start
```

Newer Linux distros comes with **systemd**. If you use a service bundled with your distro you'll get it already configured for systemd.

Since you are compiling nginx from the sources and you are using a SysV init file (**/etc/init.d/nginx**), systemd will use a generator to parse it (**systemd-sysv-generator**).

In your SysV script, you define the pid file and starts the process with:

```
NGINX_PID=/var/run/nginx.pid
...
/sbin/startproc -p $NGINX_PID $NGINX_BIN
```

If I'm not wrong you are using a SUSE Linux init script on Ubuntu (because of the **startproc** command), that startproc command only reads the pid file (specified by the **-p** parameter), it doesn't create it, thus systemd can't find a pid file and it hangs.

In your case, the solution is either to create the pid file in your SysV init script (on the **/var/run/nginx.pid** location), use an Ubuntu SysV init script, or a systemd one.

This may also happen (not what's happening to you) when you have a correct SysV init script which creates a pid file, but it's different from the one commented at the top of the file. The systemd generator reads the comments, for example this one:

```
# pidfile: /var/run/nginxd.pid
```

And uses the pidfile defined there.

#### More information:

- nginx [init scripts](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/initscripts/) for SysV init, systemd, etc.
- SysV generator processing the [pidfile comment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/sysv-generator/sysv-generator.c#L538).
- How systemd [reads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts) SysV init scripts.
- SysV generator [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysv-generator.html).
- startproc [source](ftp://ftp.suse.com/pub/projects/init/killproc-2.13.tar.gz) code (SUSE FTP site).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` is malformed. Make sure this line is set:

```
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
```

Alternatively you can copy the `[Service]` section to a new file called `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service`. Unit files placed in `/etc/systemd/system` allow you to override sections without duplicating the entire file installed by the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Inspiration https://serverfault.com/a/788576 and https://askubuntu.com/a/733604

Ubuntu 20.04

I changed two things

First: I runned service NetworkManager-wait

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Second: I added to path PIDFile (and pidfile) prefix `var`

```
[Service]
...
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
...
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /var/run/nginx.pid
..
```